# How can i append table (tr th: even and tr td:even and th:odd and td:odd) to a new table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Firstly, sorry English is not my first language.

***(Even and Odd is based on the index)**

I would like to achieve this table in mobile view.

[image]

**What i have tried**

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Content 1 Head</th>
      <th>Content 2 Head</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
     <th>Content 3 Head</th>
     <th>Content 4 Head</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Content 3</td>
     <td>Content 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

```
var mobileTable = ""
$("table tbody th:even").each(function(i) {
    var tdval = $(this).html();
    console.log(thval);
    mobileTable =+ "<th>" + $('table tr td:odd') + tdval +'</th>';
});
$('table:first-child').empty();
$('.table-mobile').append(mobileTable);
```

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error ?

Comment: This is the output:
<table class="table-mobile">NaN[object Object]Content 3 Head</table>

Comment: Please refer this code https://codepen.io/JacobLett/pen/mBQoOj @Rajesh

Comment: `$('table tr td:odd')` is an object. You might want `$('table tr td:odd').html()` instead

Comment: Hi Thum Choon Tat, I've made amendment. But is it possible to loop within a loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an array
2. Give seperate rows to each th and tds
3. Add each th to array in positions like: 0,2,4,6 `(index*2)`
4. Add each td to Array in positions like: 1,3,5,7 `(((index+1)*2)-1)`
5. Add array to mobile table using `append`.

Your final array becomes:

```
[0] = th1
[1] = td1
[2] = th2
[3] = td2
...
```

```js
var tarr = [];
$("table tr:even *").each(function(i) {
    tarr[(i*2)]="<tr><th>"+$(this).html()+"</th></tr>";
});
 $("table tr:odd *").each(function(i) {
    tarr[((i+1)*2)-1]="<tr><td>"+$(this).html()+"</td></tr>";
});
console.log(tarr);
$('table').empty();
$('.table-mobile').append(tarr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <th>Content 1 Head</th>
  <th>Content 2 Head</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Content 1</td>
  <td>Content 2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <th>Content 3 Head</th>
 <th>Content 4 Head</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Content 3</td>
 <td>Content 4</td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
<table class="table-mobile"></table>
```

Comment: Nice! Ritest Khandekar.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var  x = $("#table").find("th,td");

var i = $("#table").find("tr").length;

var j = x.length/i;
//console.log(i , j);



var newT= $("<table>").appendTo("body");
for (j1=0; j1<j;j1++){
    //var temp = $("<tr>").appendTo(newT);
    for(var i1=0;i1<i; i1++){
     var temp = $("<tr>").appendTo(newT);
        temp.append($(x[j1 *4+i1%2 *2+i1/2]).clone());
        var temp2 = $("<tr>").appendTo(newT);
        temp2.append($(x[j1 *4+i1%2 *2+i1/2+2]).clone());
        //console.log(j1 *4,i1%2 *2,i1/2);
    }
    
}

$("#table").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Content 1 Head</th>
      <th>Content 2 Head</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
     <th>Content 3 Head</th>
     <th>Content 4 Head</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Content 3</td>
     <td>Content 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Thank you, but i believe Ritesh Khandekar answer above, is easier for me to understood. Thank again!

Answer (score 0):

This is amendment made.

```
var mobileTable = ""
$("table tbody th").each(function(i) {
    var thval = $(this).html();
    var tdval = $('table tr td').html(); // How can i loop this through 
    mobileTable += "<tr><td>" + thval +'</td></tr><tr><td>'+ tdval + '</td><tr>';
});
$('table:first-child').empty();
$('.table-mobile').append(mobileTable);
```

**Result** (Triggered by jQuery)

[image]